# Native compiled stored procedure in SQL Server 2014, update table joining anothoer one for values

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, in-memory

In SQL Server 2014, I can't get it work with native compiled stored procedure.
Is it possible to modify code below to get table updated with values from another table?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[bsp_SetMinCompetitorPrices_MO]
    @spid INT,
    @MinCompetitorsPrices as dbo.bT_MinCompetitorsPrices_MO readonly
WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION, SCHEMABINDING, EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS BEGIN ATOMIC WITH
    (TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SNAPSHOT, LANGUAGE = N'us_english')
    UPDATE 
        otu
    SET
        otu.CompetitorPriceNat = mincp.MinCompetitorPrice
    FROM 
        TT_OffersToUpdate_MO otu 
    INNER JOIN
        @MinCompetitorsPrices mincp ON mincp.ConcreteProductId = otu.ConcreteProductId
    WHERE 
        otu.spid = @spid
END
```

Getting an error:

> Using the FROM clause in a DELETE or UPDATE statement is not supported with natively compiled stored procedures

I understand that, but is there any workaround for this?

Thank you